# How to parse JSONP response in python?

Tags: python, json, jsonp

[image]

How can i parse JSONP response, i tried json.loads(), but it will never work for JSONP

Comment: What does the raw JSONP response text look like?

Comment: I tried to remove padding from the string and used json.loads()

Comment: sometime it need only to remove `callback=jsonp` from url to get normal `json` - but you didn't show url so we can't check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the reading following

> JSONP is JSON with padding, that is, you put a string at the beginning
> and a pair of parenthesis around it.

I tried to remove padding from the string and used json.loads()

```
from json import loads
response = requests.get(link)
startidx = response.text.find('(')
endidx = response.text.rfind(')')
data = loads(response.text[startidx + 1:endidx])
```

it's working